# <mat-error> not working in a reactive form in an angular 8 application

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, angular-reactive-forms, angular-formbuilder

I am using a reactive approach to build a form, using angular and material. Somehow, one of the errors generated via custom validator is not showing up, while all other errors are working fine.
Below is the code.

```html
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="10px" fxLayoutAlign="center center" formGroupName="passwords">
    <!--original password-->
    <mat-form-field hintLabel="Should be at least 8 characters long">
        <input type="password" matInput placeholder="Your password" formControlName="password">
        <mat-error *ngIf="signUpForm.get('passwords.password').hasError('required')">
            Passwords cannot be blank
        </mat-error>
        <mat-error *ngIf="signUpForm.get('passwords.password').hasError('minlength')">
            Password has to be atleast 8 characters
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <!--confirmation password-->
    <mat-form-field hintLabel="Should be at least 8 characters long">
        <input type="password" matInput placeholder="Confirm password" formControlName="confirmPassword">
            <mat-error *ngIf="signUpForm.get('passwords.confirmPassword').hasError('required')">
                Passwords cannot be blank
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="signUpForm.get('passwords.confirmPassword').hasError('minlength')">
                 Password has to be atleast 8 characters
            </mat-error>  
            <mat-error *ngIf="signUpForm.get('passwords').hasError('paswordMismatch')">
                Passwords do not match
           </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>   
</div>
```

Here the <mat-error *ngIf="signUpForm.get('passwords').hasError('paswordMismatch')"> is not working.

below is the ts file

````js
    ngOnInit(): void{
    
        this.signUpForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            studentName: this.formBuilder.group({
                firstName: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z]*')]],
                middleName: [null, [Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z]*')]],
                lastName: [null, [Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z]*')]] }),
            email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email,
                  CustomEmailValidator.forbiddenEmailIds]],
            userMobNumber: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10), 
                  Validators.maxLength(10)]],
            studentID: [null, [Validators.required]],
            passwords: this.formBuilder.group({
                password: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]],
                confirmPassword: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]]
            }, {validator: this.passwordConfirming}),
            enroledProgram: [null, [Validators.required]],
            studentDepartment: [null, [Validators.required]],
            facultyDepartment: [null, [Validators.required]],
            facultyEmail: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
            facultyName: [null, [Validators.required]],
            funded: [null, [Validators.required]]
            });}
        
          passwordConfirming(c: AbstractControl): { [s: string]: boolean } { 
               console.log(c);
              if (c.get('password').value !== c.get('confirmPassword').value) {
                 return {paswordMismatch: true};
              }
          return null;
        }
    ```
````

Comment: shouldn't it be `{validator**s**: **[**this.passwordConfirming**]**}`?

Comment: I think for single validator, one need not pass an array

Comment: one possible thing I have in mind is mat errors are hidden if the control in the same form group is not touched. could you please check that? just make an error condition and focus out from the second input

Comment: I have tried that and its still not working, one thing I have noticed is that, when I post this specific mat-error outside the <mat-form-field>, it works. Also, I tried ```{{ signUpForm.get('passwords').hasError('paswordMismatch') }}```
posting this inside that <mat-form-field> to check if it is getting the error value.

Comment: it seems that default error state matcher hides your error. your could redefine your own like here https://stackblitz.com/angular/brleoyyorkap?file=app%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.ts

Comment: But why only this one, in-fact I have used custom validators in other forms of the same application and it's all working there, the only difference is I am using FormBuilder for this one.

Comment: the problem is not in custom validation. It happends because the `confirmPassword` is `valid`, and that is the reason to hide any errors related to this input. angular thinks `paswordMismatch` error is related to `confirmPassword` and hides all the errors. custom error state matcher could do the trick, or you can just mark `confirmPassword` field as `invalid` when its parent formGroup is also `invalid`

Comment: Ok, thanks. Let me try that. Thanks for the clear explanation

Comment: It's working now, thanks for the help.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

## It should be

```html
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="10px" fxLayoutAlign="center center" formGroupName="passwords">
... 
            <mat-error *ngIf="signUpForm.get('passwords.confirmPassword').hasError('paswordMismatch')">
                Passwords do not match
           </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>   
</div>
```

Comment: The validation is on the group named passwords,

Answer (score 0):

**Create another file named "password.validator.ts" and write the following code:**

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from "@angular/forms";

export function passwordValidator(
  control: AbstractControl
): {
  [key: string]: boolean;
} | null {


  const password = control.get("password");
  const confirmPassword = control.get("confirmPassword");
  if (password.pristine || confirmPassword.pristine) {
    return null;
  }
  return password && confirmPassword && password.value !== confirmPassword.value
    ? { missMatch: true }
    : null;
}
```

**on the File where the form exists: add the password validator like this-- **

```
import { passwordValidator } from "./password.validator";

this.signUpForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            passwords: this.formBuilder.group({
                password: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]],
                confirmPassword: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]]
            }, { validators: [passwordValidator]})}
```